# Unable to fetch email from created facebook test users

Tags: facebook, http, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-fql

I have created a facebook test user using Graph API with following query parameters.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<app-id>/accounts/test-users

installed = true                                  
method = post                                     
name = Test Account YNRSVOZHXO             
permission = email,public_profile                                
locale = en_US   
access_token = <app-id>|<client-secret>
```

which is giving response having id, email, access_token of the created user.

When i call the following API, I am not getting email.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=<access-token>&fields=id,name,email
```

Permissions of the test-user,

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<test-user-id>/permissions?access_token=<access-token>
```

returning

```
 {
   "data": [
    {
        "permission": "user_friends",
        "status": "granted"
    },
    {
        "permission": "public_profile",
        "status": "granted"
    }
  ]
}
```

In the dashboard, I can see the test user's email.

How do I grant email permission also, when creating test user or may be refresh access token using Graph API.

Comment: Does this test user have an email set when you look at its details in the app dashboard?

Comment: @CBroe yes. Its a test user, so its created automatically when the account is created.

Comment: Having the same problem. Have you since managed to get the email of a test user somehow?

Comment: @mbudnik please refer to the answer provided. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of query parameter **permission**, I used **permissions** and its working now.